# Как наложить Спрайты друг на друга

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть персонаж, который может кастомизироваться в игре. Он состоит из трех спрайтов: тела, одежды и волос.

[image]

Если это делать через Order in layer, то появляется проблема, при изменении прозрачности начинают просвечивать одежда, из за этого этот метод не подходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно все три спрайта последовательно наложить друг на друга, и получить один спрайт (конечный). То есть мне нужно запечь три спрайта в один. (Приветствуются другие решения этой проблемы)

Comment: А что ты хочешь чтобы происходило при изменении прозрачности? Хочешь изменять прозрачность сразу трем спрайтами? Ну ты можешь сразу у 3х страйтов менять ее

Comment: @Methorn не получится так. Попробуй в фотошопе сделать то что ты предлагаешь человеку и поймешь.

Comment: попробуй погуглить в сторону "unity combine sprites at runtime"